# Ruby/Rails: class_eval doesn't want to evaluate this code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance-eval, class-eval

To generate mocks for Omniauth, I Added this method to `config/environments/development.rb`

```
  def provides_mocks_for(*providers)
    providers.each do |provider|
      class_eval %Q{
        OmniAuth.config.add_mock(provider, {
          :uid => '123456',
          :provider => provider,
          :nickname => 'nickname',
          :info => {
            'email' => "#{provider}@webs.com",
            'name' => 'full_name_' + provider
          }
        })
      }
    end
  end
```

then I call in the same file:

```
provides_mocks_for :facebook, :twitter, :github, :meetup
```

But I get:

```
3.1.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/singleton_class.rb:11:in `class_eval': can't create instance of singleton class (TypeError)
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in ruby metaprogramming, but maybe you want [`instance_eval`](http://ilikestuffblog.com/2009/01/09/fun-with-rubys-instance_eval-and-class_eval/)?

Comment: Why do you use `*_eval` at all? Just call your method without the eval. Your current code even looks like this.

Comment: @Sergio I get `instance_eval: can't convert Symbol into String (TypeError)`

Comment: @HolgerJust You rock ! Can you add this as an answer so that I accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class_eval`and `module_eval` (which are equivalent) are used to evaluate and immediately execute strings as Ruby code. As such they can be used as a meta-programming facility to dynamically create methods. An example is

```
class Foo
  %w[foo bar].each do |name|
    self.class_eval <<-RUBY, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
      def #{name}
        puts '#{name}'
      end
    RUBY
  end
end
```

It will create two methods `foo` and `bar` which print their respective values. As you can see, I create a string containing the actual source code of the function and pass it into `class_eval`.

While this is a very capable instrument of executing dynamically created code, it must be used with great care. If you make errors here, BAD THINGS WILL HAPPEN™. E.g. if you use user-supplied values when generating code, make *really* sure the variables contain only values you expect. Eval-based function should generally be used as the last resort.

A cleaner and generally preferred variant is to use `define_method` like so:

```
class Foo
  %w[foo bar].each do |name|
    define_method name do
      puts name
    end
  end
end
```

(Note that MRI is a wee bit faster with the eval variant. But that doesn't matter most of the time when compared to the added safety and clarity.)

Now in your given code, you effectively write code into a string that can be run directly. Using `class_eval` here leads to the string being executed in the context of the top-most object (`Kernel` in this case). As this is a special singleton object which can't be instanciated (similar to nil, true and false), you get this error.

However, as you create directly executable code, you don't need to use `class_eval` (or any form of eval) at all. Just run your code in a loop as is. And always remember: meta-programming variants (of which the eval methods are among the most bad-ass) should only be used as the last resort.